# Node.Js : How to log a request's body without access to the Request object

Tags: node.js, request, botframework

I'm currently using a framework in Node.js ( [the `botbuilder` module from Microsoft Bot Framework](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder)) which uses the `request`[[2]](https://github.com/request/request) module to make HTTP requests.

I'm encountering a problem : this framework seems to send a malformed JSON to Microsoft's servers, but I fail to see why and what is this JSON message made of.

So I'm looking for a way to log those messages, to take a peek at this malformed JSON, as I don't have access to the request object (unless I heavily alter the framework code, which is not something one shall do)

So far, I'm able to log the response body (by adding `request` to the NODE_DEBUG environment variable), but not the original request body. I did try a `tcpdump` on our server but since it's all HTTPS there's nothing I can use there.

Any idea / tool that might help ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: A good web debugging proxy is an absolute must in any webdeveloper's toolbox, something like https://www.charlesproxy.com/ or http://www.telerik.com/fiddler It allows you to inspect requests and responses, simulate slow connections through throttling and lots and lots more

Comment: Mind you, I'm not creating a browser-based web application. I thought about a server-side proxy but I assume it will raise security alerts, as proxies aren't supposed to be able to decipher encrypted traffic.

Comment: In Charles you can have SSL proxying https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/

Comment: Can you provide a code example that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use Node.js middleware to log all your requests. For example, you could use the module [request-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-debug).

Another popular request logging middleware worth knowing about is [Morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan), from the Express.js server team.

Comment: On the page you link about `request-debug` : "Does not work with request versions older than 2.22.0 (July 2013). Tests don't start passing until version 2.28.0 (December 2013)"

Comment: And it seems that Morgan is used to produce "server-oriented" logs (you log the activity of your `express` server), which is not what the `request` module is about in my case.

Comment: `request-debug` is exactly what I needed. Fyi to others: you only need to add a single line of code to get useful debug information: `require('request-debug')(request);`